# Maven project: SolrJ with slf4j and logback logging causes SolrException: Error loading class 'org.slf4j.Logger;org.slf4j.Logger'

Tags: spring, maven, logback, slf4j, solrj

I have got the following setup: A Spring application that makes use of SolrJ with slf4j logging over logback. When I start the application on my tomcat server the below error appears. So, somehow SolrJ does not find the slf4j logging component, but I verified that the according .jar file is actually in the correct lib folder of my WAR.

```
2017-05-12 09:37:54,094 WARN  [org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.slf4j.Logger;org.slf4j.Logger'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:556)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:625)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:590)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:583)
    at org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher.createWatcher(LogWatcher.java:181)
    at org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher.newRegisteredLogWatcher(LogWatcher.java:134)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:473)
    at de.imi.MDMJava.config.AppConfig.solrClient(AppConfig.java:259)
    at de.imi.MDMJava.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ece8fb2.CGLIB$solrClient$9(<generated>)
    at de.imi.MDMJava.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ece8fb2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2023340f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at de.imi.MDMJava.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ece8fb2.solrClient(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1692)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:415)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/slf4j/Logger;org/slf4j/Logger
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:540)
    ... 103 common frames omitted
] in LogWatcher.java:createWatcher:184: Unable to load LogWatcher org.slf4j.Logger;org.slf4j.Logger: {}
2017-05-12 09:37:55,991 WARN  [] in WebSecurity.java:performBuild:300:
```

My pom.xml for the loggin part looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the Maven dependency tree looks as follow:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep slf4j
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.7)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
```

Unfortunately the full dependency tree is too long for this post, but if you need any further information just let me know. Thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit 1**:

There is a "slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar" file in my "/WEB-INF/lib/" directory of my WAR file that contains all libraries.

The full Maven dependency tree where I stripped the parts that don't contain "slf4j":

```
[more dependencies, but no occurence of slf4j...]
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.7)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-openid:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.openid4java:openid4java-nodeps:jar:0.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.20:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.0.b2)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.3:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:6.5.1:compile
[more dependencies, but no occurence of slf4j...]
[INFO] |  +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.servlet:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:6.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.2.3)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.noggit:noggit:jar:0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- (ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5.4)
[INFO] |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.4.1)
[INFO] |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.10)
[INFO] +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-extras:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet-wildcard:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-mustache:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:12.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 14.0.1)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:3.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-autotag-core-runtime:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-jsp:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-freemarker:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:3.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:3.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-freemarker:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.15:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-velocity:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:3.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:3.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.2)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.2)
[INFO] |  |  |     +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.6)
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-velocity:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-el:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-mvel:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-ognl:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- ognl:ognl:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- jboss:javassist:jar:3.7.ga:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-compat:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:3.0.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:12.0.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 14.0.1)
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.10:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.2:provided
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:jquery:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:3.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.webjars:jquery:jar:1.11.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.0)
[INFO] +- org.webjars.bower:devbridge-autocomplete:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.webjars.bower:jquery:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:webjars-locator:jar:0.32:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.8.8)
[INFO] \- com.github.dpaukov:combinatoricslib3:jar:3.1.1:compile
```

**Edit 2**:

Here is the content of the slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar in the WAR package. The "org/slf4j/Logger.class" seems to exist. When I deploy the webapp, slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar has 644 rights and my user is the owner of the file. Can that cause the problem?

```
slf4j-api-1.7.25
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── maven
│       └── org.slf4j
│           └── slf4j-api
│               ├── pom.properties
│               └── pom.xml
└── org
    └── slf4j
        ├── event
        │   ├── EventConstants.class
        │   ├── EventRecodingLogger.class
        │   ├── Level.class
        │   ├── LoggingEvent.class
        │   └── SubstituteLoggingEvent.class
        ├── helpers
        │   ├── BasicMarker.class
        │   ├── BasicMarkerFactory.class
        │   ├── BasicMDCAdapter$1.class
        │   ├── BasicMDCAdapter.class
        │   ├── FormattingTuple.class
        │   ├── MarkerIgnoringBase.class
        │   ├── MessageFormatter.class
        │   ├── NamedLoggerBase.class
        │   ├── NOPLogger.class
        │   ├── NOPLoggerFactory.class
        │   ├── NOPMDCAdapter.class
        │   ├── SubstituteLogger.class
        │   ├── SubstituteLoggerFactory.class
        │   ├── Util$1.class
        │   ├── Util.class
        │   └── Util$ClassContextSecurityManager.class
        ├── ILoggerFactory.class
        ├── IMarkerFactory.class
        ├── Logger.class
        ├── LoggerFactory.class
        ├── Marker.class
        ├── MarkerFactory.class
        ├── MDC$1.class
        ├── MDC.class
        ├── MDC$MDCCloseable.class
        └── spi
            ├── LocationAwareLogger.class
            ├── LoggerFactoryBinder.class
            ├── MarkerFactoryBinder.class
            └── MDCAdapter.class
```

**Edit 3**:
@AlexC you were right. I grepped for ".Logger;" and found this line in my solr.xml:

```
<str name="class">${loggingClass:org.slf4j.Logger;org.slf4j.Logger}</str>
```

I changed it to:

```
<logging>
    <str name="class">${loggingClass:org.slf4j.Logger}</str>
    <str name="enabled">${loggingEnabled:true}</str>
    <watcher>
      <int name="size">${loggingSize:50}</int>
      <str name="threshold">${loggingThreshold:WARN}</str>
    </watcher>
  </logging>
```

Still the same error but now with "org.slf4j.Logger" instead (with jcl-over-slf4j, logback-core and without):

```
2017-05-12 14:33:16,411 WARN  [java.lang.ClassCastException: interface org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:540)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:625)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:590)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:583)
    at org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher.createWatcher(LogWatcher.java:181)
    at org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher.newRegisteredLogWatcher(LogWatcher.java:134)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:473)
    [...]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
] in LogWatcher.java:createWatcher:184: Unable to load LogWatcher org.slf4j.Logger: {}
```

**Edit 4**:

Maybe to clarify this for everyone from my below comment: "Solr is integrated into my application via SolrJ. I do not run a separate Solr instance. I know this should only be done for debugging purpose but my usage of Solr does not justify a standalone Solr server."

I tried to removed all dependencies of slf4j via exclusions in my pom.xml. The only remaining dependencies are now:

```
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- (ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
```

Comment: just check in your runtime environment (e.g. in your WAR/EAR etc), is slf4j-api.jar exists

Comment: You should post the parts of dependency three that show what are the roots of the conflicts. Or at least one, the first root of the conflict.

Comment: I added a edit for your comments. The slf4j-api.jar exists in my WAR file.

Comment: that looks strange.. can you extract the content of slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar in your WAR, and make sure that `org/slf4j/Logger.class` exists?  I kind of suspect either the JAR is having something wrong, or your deployment of WAR is having some problem

Comment: Can you try removing the jcl-over-slf4j and logback-core, you only need slf4j-api and logback-classic to have it work.  Then if that still gives you the same error, add -verbose to your startup and check what is being loaded.

Comment: I also find the exception weird, it's looking for 'org/slf4j/Logger;org/slf4j/Logger'  I expected to see 'org/slf4j/Logger'  can you check the config and make sure you don't have a typo or something is't accedentally separated by ; when it should be :  (platform thing windows/unix)

Comment: Your were right, I had a typo in my solr.xml. The error remains though.

Comment: could you post your project on github or somewhere we could take a look at your work?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy your war in the same jetty where is running Solr?

Comment: Exactly my Spring application and the SolrJ instance are packed into the same WAR and are thus deployed together. Not in Jetty though, I am using a Tomcat server.

Comment: Which version of solr do you have deployed in tomcat? AFAIK you're using SolrJ 6.5.1 and you cannot deploy Solr 6.5.1 in Tomcat.

Comment: Solr is integrated into my application via SolrJ. I do not run a separate Solr instance. I know this should only be done for debugging purpose but my usage of Solr does not justify a standalone Solr server. PS: Yes, I run SolrJ/Solr 6.5.1.

Comment: This explains a lot of things, I think your problems are related to an overlap of logging configuration between Solr and Tomcat. That's why you have a `'org/slf4j/Logger;org/slf4j/Logger'` exception. I suggest to add an `exclusion` in all your Solr dependencies for the slf4j logging framework hoping that this will force Solr to use running Tomcat logging.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately no success (see edit). The `'org/slf4j/Logger;org/slf4j/Logger'` exception was due to a misconfiguration in my solr.xml, see edit 3.  Now it is only `'org.slf4j.Logger'`. Btw thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround for my setup. First I added all kind of connectors to slf4j logging into my pom.xml, due to the following sentence 
 in the [Solr wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging#A_note_about_SLF4J_intercept_jars).

> If you use an entirely different logging mechanism like logback, then
>   you must have intercepts for all three - JUL, JCL, and log4j.

Furthermore I found the Solr Code that causes my logging problems in the class LogWatcher.java line 184 (also see exception message in my question). Here is an excerpt of the code from [Github](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/logging/LogWatcher.java).

```
  private static LogWatcher createWatcher(LogWatcherConfig config, SolrResourceLoader loader) {

    String fname = config.getLoggingClass();
    String slf4jImpl;

    try {
      slf4jImpl = StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton().getLoggerFactoryClassStr();
      log.debug("SLF4J impl is " + slf4jImpl);
      if (fname == null) {
        if ("org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory".equals(slf4jImpl)) {
          fname = "Log4j";
        } else if (slf4jImpl.indexOf("JDK") > 0) {
          fname = "JUL";
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
      log.warn("Unable to read SLF4J version.  LogWatcher will be disabled: " + e);
      if (e instanceof OutOfMemoryError) {
        throw (OutOfMemoryError) e;
      }
      return null;
    }

    if (fname == null) {
      log.debug("No LogWatcher configured");
      return null;
    }

    if ("JUL".equalsIgnoreCase(fname))
      return new JulWatcher(slf4jImpl);
    if ("Log4j".equals(fname))
      return new Log4jWatcher(slf4jImpl);

    try {
      return loader != null ? loader.newInstance(fname, LogWatcher.class) : null;
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
      log.warn("Unable to load LogWatcher {}: {}", fname, e);
      if (e instanceof OutOfMemoryError) {
        throw (OutOfMemoryError) e;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

The problematic part is the last try/catch block, so it seems like fname == "org.slf4j.Logger" is not valid. However, as we can see at the top of the code if fname == null the string "Log4j" is used as fall back. So, I simply decided to go with "Log4j" in my solr logging configuration (as shown below) and let the log4j-over-slf4j connector handle the connection to slf4j.

```
<solr>

    ...

    <logging>
        <str name="class">Log4j</str>
        <bool name="enabled">true</bool>
        <!-- default watcher param -->
        <watcher>
            <int name="size">50</int>
            <str name="threshold">FINEST</str>
        </watcher>
    </logging>

    ...

</solr>
```

I guess this is not the perfect solution, but for me it seems like a good enough work around.